# Manual for DIAGNOSTICS II V1.2 – CPU TEST SUPERSOFT ASSOCIATES

Tags: 8080

I am building a 8080 emulator.  I found some useful test suites [here](/q/670).  The emulator passes the first test suite (8080/8085 CPU Diagnostic, version 1.0, by Microcosm Associates), but not the second (DIAGNOSTICS II V1.2 – CPU TEST SUPERSOFT ASSOCIATES).  Is there a manual (or other document) for this diagnostic tool?  (The tool gives some probably useful diagnostic codes.)

Comment: Are you asking for _the_ manual only, or would any documentation that answers what the diagnostic codes are do?

Comment: all documentation is welcome

Comment: I could not find any other way to contact you; if you want to spend a lot of money for it, there's an actual copy of the original diskettes and manuals available on [eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/181766516759) right now.

Comment: @A.Wilcox : Too much... but thx for the info.